# Close reason as belongs to ServerFault and SuperUser

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm here on the DevOps SE for not so long, but already noticed that some of the questions are generally a better fit for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and are subjects to a migration.

Would it make sense to add Server Fault and Super User to the list of sites to migrate to when closing as off-topic for this site? Currently, we have just "DevOps meta" there (at least that's what I see):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't setup migration path during beta phase but diamond moderators can migrate a question to any site.

I assume the proper path would be to VTC with a custom reason and flag for moderator attention when there's more than 3 votes agreeing this is a proper destination (if we don't catch it by ourselves).

We (moderators) would check with proposed target site moderators to ensure it would be acceptable on their sites before.